# Is complete URL redirect possible in .htaccess*

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a lot of URL, which can't be redirected, or, better, rewrited with mod_rewrite in .htaccess, so instead rewriting, I have created 301 redirects manually. It isn't too much records, about 40 redirects, and I am basically copying URL from Excel table.

For example:

## This redirects work

```
redirect 301 /about-us/go-social/ http://www.somesite.com/about-us/
redirect 301 /about-us/team/John/ http://www.somesite.com/about-us/
```

And whole bunch of similar redirects, and then about then redirects like this, which don't work:

## This redirects don't work

```
redirect 301 http://m.somesite.com/site/somesite/faqs http://www.somesite.com/faqs/
```

Can I redirect complete URL in that way, or is there another solution?

## Still this isn't working

```
# Single URL 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m\.somesite\.com\.au$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^site/somesite/faqs/?$ http://www.somesite.com.au/faqs/ [NC,L,R=301]

# Global subdomain redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m\.somesite\.com\.au  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.somesite.com.au/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Cross post on Webmasters: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/84476/how-to-do-301-redirect-for-complete-url

Comment: Should I delete question or asks mod to delete it?

Comment: I would just leave it for the mods to _close_ (if anything). Since it has a valid answer, it would be a shame to delete it IMO. Apache/.htaccess is admittedly a bit of a middle ground since it is on-topic for both sites.

Comment: I agree with you. On first it was logical to put it on SO, but actually belongs to web masters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't with redirect:

> **Redirect [status] URL-path URL**
>
> The Redirect directive maps an old URL
> into a new one by asking the client to refetch the resource at the new
> location.
>
> The old URL-path is a case-sensitive (%-decoded) path beginning with a
> slash. A relative path is not allowed. The new URL should be an
> absolute URL beginning with a scheme and hostname. In Apache HTTP
> Server 2.2.6 and later, a URL-path beginning with a slash may also be
> used, in which case the scheme and hostname of the current server will
> be added.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect

But it's possible with rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteRule ^about-us/(?:go-social|team/John)/?$ http://www.somesite.com/about-us/ [NC,L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m\.somesite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^site/somesite/faqs/?$ http://www.somesite.com/faqs/ [NC,L,R=301]
```

But one RewriteCond for each. You can combine them if they lead to the same address.

Comment: @Croieses, that's neat. Can you give me a quick explanation of second and third lines?

Comment: I have added this last 2 lines to my .htaccess file, but it isn't working. See edited answer.

Comment: What's the problem ? If you redirect all the subdomain, no need to add single url after... or to redirect to an other url, add the single URL before global subdomain redirect

Comment: Not sure what am I doing wrong. I have created subdomain, set document root to public_html, and create single URL redirect, but redirect for that URL doesn't work. For global subdomain it works. Maybe I have to escape dots in domain.com.au?

Comment: I change your code. Try now with single URL before global redirect